# Config file changed by PHP hackers with no clue of entry

Tags: php

Well i have a script (It's secure for what i know. e.g. No direct file access using die()). Coded in PHP. But hackers would access the "conf.php" file and change its contents. But not all.

Normal File:

```
<?php
   /*
    * Some license
    */
     $conf['mysql_host'] = 'localhost';
     //some other details
?>
```

After hackers changed it:

```
Hi, we luve uhhhh<?php
 /*
  * Some license
  */
   $conf['mysql_host'] = 'locahost'];
   //Some other details
?>
```

Any solution? Please help. Oh and i did clean variables to prevent any XXS and SQL-injection attacks.

Comment: Does this happen in some shared hosting environment? I don't know what could allow this other than some other php script touches it... or maybe via FTP. Or... do you have some script somewhere that is allowed to write to files? Some web file browser?

Comment: Hey they love you, nice. Just kidding. It's nearly impossible to tell what the problem was without very detailed information. Check your access-log files maybe there you find some answers on how they got in.

Comment: Is this your own PHP code? Or an app you've downloaded? If the latter I'd guess you've left a config script around that's used to write to this config file and that's how they got in. Make sure only files that need to be writeable by the we server are writeable.

Comment: Well, i do have an API that updates the file remotely whenever there;s an update available. But i didn't see any changes to the API file itself. It's Weird. I can't access/find the server logs any. Maybe because i'm not admin on the server as i am using shared hosting at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make a backup of the machine in the compromised state and restore it to a known good configuration. In most cases, this means a reinstallation. Unfortunately, there is no other feasible way to clean all the backdoors the attacker may have left in your system.

You may also want to disconnect the machine temporarily. Since it has been hacked, it is probably used for illegal activities, and you may have a legal duty to suspend these asap.

Then, analyze your code to find the vulnerability. An XSS or SQL injection should **not** allow an attacker to insert php code. After you have closed the vulnerability (and have audited the code for other, or at least similar vulnerabilities), you can reinstall your php scripts and reconnect the machine to the internet.

Comment: From the backup you may be able to identify how they got in. Compare the edit date/time on the config file with your logs and see if you can see any suspicious activity at the same time.

Comment: @liquorvicar Note that generic file times are not reliable and can easily be manipulated. However, the amateurish change of the config file paints a picture of an incompetent attacker who has probably forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by a previous answer, it's probably not an XSS or SQL injection. It could be from outside (e.g. another site on the same server), but you should check your code for places where it could allow execution of arbitrary commands. Most probable vulnerabilities are:

- an include/require that takes user input without proper sanitization
- an eval()
- program execution functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php